# A problem in understanding the Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

So, IVT essentially says *if a function $f$ is continuous over an interval $[a,b]$, then the function $f$ will take up all the values between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ at least once at some point in the interval $[a,b]$.*

Now, suppose $f$ is continuous between $[3,7]$ and $f(3) = 4$ and $f(7) = 25$

According to IVT, $f(3) = 4 < m < 25 = f(7)$, i.e., the function takes up all the values between $f(3)$ and $f(7)$ at least once in the interval. But, according to the below picture, clearly, the function within that interval takes up values different that do not satisfy the above inequality. **Please help me fill the gap in my understanding of IVT here.**

Please do correct me if I'm mistaken.[image]

*This doubt arose from the below KhanAcademy question*
[image]

Comment: IVT doesn't tell you that ALL values must be between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ -- it tells you that every value between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ must be attained.

Comment: The IVT says that $f$ reaches all values between $f(3)$ and $f(7)$. It doesn't say it can't reach other values as well.

Comment: @NickPeterson But isn't this possible?

Comment: Isn't *what* possible?

Comment: @SathvikR. If it helps: you seem to be interpreting it as: $x\in(a,b)$ implies $f(x)\in (f(a), f(b))$ (assuming $f(a)<f(b)$, etc).  But the actual implication is: for all $y\in (f(a), f(b))$, there exists $x\in(a, b)$ so that $f(x)=y$.

Comment: IVT *only* says that all values between $4$ and $25$ will be obtained.  And in that picture they clearly all are.  The IVT says *NOTHING* at all about values outside $[4,25]$.  It doesn't say they *are* obtained.  It doesn't say they *aren't* obtained.

Comment: Okay.... it says that every possible output value between $f(3) = 4$ and $f(7) = 25$ will be obtained *somewhere* in the interval between $3$ and $7$.  But it doesn't say that values between $4$ and $25$ are the *only* values obtained.   If I told you that every dog in the Golden Gate Dog shelter has an owner who lives in San Francisco, that does not mean everyone who lives in San Francisco owns a dog in the Golden Gate Dog shelter.... to be continued....

Comment: @fleablood: apart from the golden gate bridge you have made the golden gate dog shelter famous. :D

Comment: And it the exact same here.  Every $\color{blue}{\text{output value between 4 and 25}}$ is obtained somewhere $\color{red}{\text{in the input values between 3 and 7}}$.  But that does not mean that every $\color{red}{\text{ input value between 3 and 7}}$ obtains $\color{blue}{\text{an output value between 4 and 25}}$.

Comment: @fleablood Thank you so much for such an intuitive explanation. Cleared my doubts

Comment: @fleablood In the KhanAcademy picture I attached, so I can interpret the solution as being the following:-

Comment: @fleablood According to IVT, f(x) = 3 such that x ϵ [-1,5] . But in the other intervals, i.e., [2,4] and [4,5] it may or may not be possible and for simplicity, KA simply marked the other intervals as wrong answers. Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: The question is which intervals *MUST* have $g(x)=3$.  Every interval *might* have $g(x)=3$ but the only one that *must* would be $[-1, 2]$ ad $g(-1) = 0 < 3 < 4 = g(2)$ so $g(x)$ must hit the value $3$ somewhere between $0$ and $2$.  We don't know how or how many times it will hit but it *can't* "jump" from less than $3$ to more than $3$ without passing "through" $3$.  The other intervals could do just about anything the want and could go wild and hit $3$ or they could do a straight shot from endpoint to endpoint.

Comment: "and for simplicity, KA simply marked the other intervals as wrong answers"  It's not for simplicity.  They asked a *specific* question:  Which interval *MUST* contain an $x$ where $g(x)=3$.  And $[-1,2]$ is the only interval that *must*.  Had the question been which intervals *might* the correct answer would be all of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The intermediate value theorem tells you that, in that context, for each $y\in[4,25]$, there is some $x\in[3,4]$ such that $f(x)=y$. It does **not** tell you that if $x\in[3,4]$, then $f(x)\in[4,25]$. So, there is no contradiction if $f\bigl([3,4]\bigr)$ contains values outside $[4,25]$.